# guardar dos objetos relacionados

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Buenas estoy realizando una API, tengo dos Modelos uno es Requisito y TipoRequisito.La relacion entre ambos es un TipoRequisito tiene muchos requisitos y un Requisito pertenece a un TipoRequisito, estoy usando Postman para poder probar los metodos.Quiero crear un requisito que a la tiene un TipoRequisito.

[image: JSON de crear Requisito]

actualmente el metodo create funciona ,pero ago otra consulta para poder mandar el objeto tipo.

```
 public function create(array $data)
{

    $modelSaved =  $this->model->create([
        "nombre" => $data["nombre"],
        "descripcion" => $data["descripcion"],
        "numeroArchivos" => $data["numeroArchivos"],
        "tipoArchivo" => $data["tipoArchivo"],
        "estado" => 1,
        "tipo_id" => $data["tipo"]["id"]
    ]);
    return $this->find($modelSaved->id)->with("tipo")->first();


}
```

El detalle es que estoy volviendo a consultar sobre ese requisito creado, no hay un mecanismo para que te devuelva la instancia del objeto creado.Estoy utilizado laravel 5.1

Comment: Si todo esta correctamente relacionado, deberías poder acceder al tipo de requisito como: $modelSaved->tipoRequisito o como se llame el método que retorna la información de la tabla relacionada.

Comment: @BryanRetamal quiero enviar todo el objeto creado como tambien la relacion TipoRequisito

Comment: Tendrías que crear un resource que te diera esta respuesta formateada (incluida la relación) o utilizar el "with" pero a partir de tu objeto creado para buscar el objeto relacionado o incluir manualmente el objeto de relación como atributo del objeto creado. Hay muchas formas, utiliza la que mas te acomode. Creo también que si llamas al atributo TipoRequisito antes de pasarlo a la respuesta, al objeto automáticamente se le agrega el objeto de relación, pero no estoy seguro de esto ultimo.